# What was the base for Japanese numbers?

Tags: history, mathematics

I'm curious what the numerical base the Japanese used before their introduction to the wider western world.

I've been taught in my Japanese language classes that they move the comma to a different place (1'0000 rather than 1,000) but that's just a question of notation and have learned that there have been a great number of loan words in Japanese.

I'm curious what they used before they met the Portuguese, for example, in 1543.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on counting rods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_rods).

Comment: Wikipedia has a [list of cultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_10#Other_bases) that use (or used) bases other than 10.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to read [Japanese numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals). So 1'0000 is called `万`, which is also used in Greek as [myriad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad).